# Gaussian integral with Vandermonde determinant

Tags: integration, random-matrices, gaussian

I want to compute the following integral, which contains a Gaussian piece and a Vandermonde determinant:
$$
\int d^Nx \,e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^N a_k x_k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^N b_k x_k} \Delta(x),
$$
where
$$
\Delta(x) = \prod_{i<j} (x_i - x_j).
$$
I am aware of the following formula, in the case that all $a_k = 1$:
$$
\int d^Nx \,e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^N x_k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^N b_k x_k} \Delta(x) = \Delta(b) e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_k b_k^2}.
$$
This is easily proven: shift $x_i \to x_i + b_i$, then the resulting integrals over $x_i$ give a polynomial in $b_i$ that is antisymmetric under any exchange of $b_i \leftrightarrow b_j$. Hence it must be proportional to the Vandermonde determinant $\Delta(b)$. In this proof, the antisymmetry in $b_i$ crucially relies on the fact that we can swap $x_k \leftrightarrow x_l$ in the $x$-integral, at the cost of a minus sign from $\Delta(x)$.

However, when $a_k \neq 1$, we can no longer swap $x_k$'s freely since the potential $\sum_k a_k x_k^2$ will be different. So, I do not expect the answer to be proportional to $\Delta(b)$. My question is, does anybody know a closed form for the integral above with general coefficients $a_k$?